# JQuery/Ajax Cascading DropDown on javaScript blocked browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, cascadingdropdown

I will use Jquery or Ajax cascading dropdown lists feature with a web service written in c#.

The web site will be an e-commerce web site so the visitors could be out-of-date human beings and so their browsers javaScript feature could be blocked.

so what should I do on that point? I am developing on asp.net 3.5 with web forms.

what kind of escapes are there here? it is ok for me if a client selects an option on the first dropdown and make a postback and get to the second dropdown with filitered options.

Answer (score 0):

you could implement the "hijax" technique to have it work with javascript disabled browsers. BUUUUT I don't think you can achieve auto post back on a drop down list without ANY javascript..the user would have to hit a form submit button (which you can auto submit...but again you'd need to use javascript).